# Gradle Errors When Opening Projects on Different Computer

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to transfer a project from one computer to another, but I've been running into a lot of gradle errors. After clearing the cache, fixing some build tools versions in the gradle files and such, I've come to this error:

Gradle project fresh failed
Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\User\Kathy\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specificed)
C:\User\Kathy\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specificed)

Right now, my AndroidManifest.xml file is located here:
C:\User\Kathy\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

The difference is that the src folder is located in the app folder, which is in MyProject, rather than the src folder being directly in MyProject. If I move the src folder into MyProject, I can open my project fine.

I was just wondering if I'm supposed to move my src folder or if there's another way to fix this - all of my other Android Studio projects have the manifest file located in app\src\main. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio you should work with a structure like this:

```
root
  module
    build.gradle
    src
      main
        java
        res
        AndroidManifest.xml
```

You can move the AndroidManifest, but you have to specify it in your `module/build.gradle` file.

Something like:

```
sourceSets {
   main {
     manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
     //....
   }
}
```

In any case you shoudn't move this file in your root project folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't changed or moved anything from the folder when transferring - I just copied the project folder and pasted it onto a new computer. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error still. I just keep getting error after error every time I solve one.